# Logging with Logger under Android

Tags: java, android, logging

I've noticed that the following works on PC but not inside the Android simulator.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("foo");
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Number is: {0}", new Object[]{new Integer(42)});
```

It just prints

```
Number is: {0}
```

Why does this fail for android?

Comment: Use Android's logging tools, references: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: What do you mean with failing?

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention this

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution in a roundabout way.  Ultimately, I think there is a Formatter somewhere in the default android logging implementation which is rendering just the message, ignoring the params.  You should be able to use the Logging API to install a formatter of your own design.

I had already installed a new Handler for a totally separate reason.  The source I used is available here: http://4thline.org/projects/download/misc/

The handler is in the *teleal-common-1.0.14-source.tar.gz* archive.  Follow the path to **src\main\java\org\fourthline\android\util\FixedAndroidHandler.java**.

This site also provides code to install this handler, but it's in a different archive: *sash-1.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz*.  Locate **1.0\src\main\java\org\teleal\common\logging\LoggingUtil.java**.

You can install this handler by making this call somewhere in your app startup code:

```
LoggingUtil.resetRootHandler(new FixedAndroidHandler());
```

What I found was that the Formatter for this Handler is embedded as an anonymous class inside the Handler.  How convenient.  I could see that the Formatter did not process the parameters passed in via the LogRecord.  I just added an "else-if" condition:

```
private static final Formatter THE_FORMATTER = new Formatter() {
    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord r) {
        String msg = r.getMessage();
        Object[] params = r.getParameters();
        Throwable thrown = r.getThrown();
        if (thrown != null) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            sw.write(r.getMessage());
            sw.write("\n");
            thrown.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.flush();
            return sw.toString();
        } else if ((params != null) && (params.length > 0) && (msg.indexOf("{0") >= 0)) {
            return MessageFormat.format(msg, params);
        } else {
            return r.getMessage();
        }
    }
};
```

The if test is consistent with other log formatting code I've seen.  In theory you should be able to take a more direct approach of installing a similar Formatter to an existing Handler.  I haven't tried this myself due to the fact that the above solution is working for me.

Comment: My concerns are the same as ejoerns: I have a lot of controller-tier code that is already written to run in a desktop environment and should be reusable.  I can't go back and alter all of that code to be android-specific by trying to import the android Log class.  The java.util.logging implementation on android finally defers to the android Log anyway, so in the end it's compatible with LogCat and whatever else you'd use Log for.  It's just got a few gaps to be plugged.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish the same `String` formatting using the static [`String.format(String format, Object... args)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method:

```
Log.d(TAG, String.format("Number is: %d", new Integer(42)));
```

Comment: Yes,this is the way I am doing that currently, but i would prefer if the `{0}`-Version would work, too because it is in a library that i want to use both for an android and a pc app.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
android.util.Log.i(TAG,  "Number is: " + number);
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: Yes, I know that Log is the preferred way on Android. But I was suprised why in general the Logger class works on Android but the formatting method does not.