# Enable logging in external library

Tags: java, android, square

I am using [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) library from square(added as a jar dependency), which has a logger configured. ([link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/http/RestAdapter.java#L45))

```
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RestAdapter.class.getName());
```

How can I enable logging in this library (from my application).

I see check like [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/http/RestAdapter.java#L202)

```
if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
          logResponseBody(url, body, statusCode, elapsedTime);
        }
```

so it looks like, I may have to get this logger and set the log level. Or does java logger read loglevel setting from config file, environment, class path ??

I am not familiar with java platform. Any help to log the messages from this (external) library in console is appreciated. For example, I need to see all the log message from this class (RestAdapter) in my android console / logCat (which is set at verbose level).

thanks.

### EDIT 1:

I added the below to my entry point, and I could see it is been called. Still no relavent log

```
static final String LOGGER_NAME = "retrofit.http.RestAdapter";

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Logger mLoggerInstance = Logger.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);
        if (mLoggerInstance != null) {
            mLoggerInstance.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        }
    }
```

### EDIT 2:

I edited the external library to change reference of loglevel FINE to DEBUG. THis let me see the log, still wonder the same effect can be achieved through logger configuration alone.

I see a post here, but didn't work.
[Logging with Logger under Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405482/logging-with-logger-under-android)

Not certain, but it looks like the debug level below Debug is suppressed in Android. ([source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/logging/AndroidHandler.java#L160))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Java Logging API. By default it uses global jre/lib/logging.properties config file. You can copy it to your application folder, change it and pass it as java arg

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties ...
```

read Oracle's overview 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html or this article http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html for mmore details

Comment: +1 thanks. With your hint, I looked at how to configure util.log for Android. I tried as explained in the Edit above. Not sure I can change the java flag in Android app.